# Are creative play sets compatible with Duplo?

Tags: compatibility, duplo

Are are the blocks in the Creative Play sets compatible with LEGO Duplo blocks? Also, are they the same size as Duplo, or Juniors or in between?

Answer (score 2):

Duplo bricks are twice (in each dimension) the size of regular bricks, and it's not hard to mix them, look for instance at the top related question (look in the right side). All the Creative Play-boxes I found in a quick search seems to bear the Duplo logo, meaning that they *are* Duplo, so of course they are compatible.